# Is there any way in the new windows 8 / windows phone 8 api to dynamically resize the tile?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

Is there any way in the new windows 8 / windows phone 8 api to dynamically resize the tile ?

Given that we have an app displaying messages on it's tile,
When we have no important message,
Our tile can be small, like an icon

Given that we have an app displaying messages on it's tile,
When we have some important message,
Resize the tile to fit that important message.

You got the idea, how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 8, developers cannot control the size of the tile.  It is entirely up to the user.

Comment: Consider indicating that there is a message on the small tile, even if you cannot appropriately display the message.  If your messages are compelling enough, the user will give you the large tile space.

Answer (score 0):

Same story with the Windows Phone 8, seems there won't be any way to programmatically change the size of your tile. I would recommend to show special alert icon or badge as part of tile image in this case. You can also show toast message to notify user.